# Noncommutative fusion categories

Tags: rt.representation-theory, fusion-categories

Although noncommutativeness is almost a defining trait for fusion categories, offhand I recall only the extended Haagerup N-N (rank 8). It's a two minute computation to find that even a based ring will be necessarily commutative for rank 4 or below. Still much space inbetween, so is it known which is the *smallest* rank that allows a noncommutative a) based ring b) fusion category?

Comment: Does $\text{Vec}_G$ for non-Abelian finite group $G$ count as noncommutative fusion categories? The smallest of those is rank 6.

Comment: Doesn't matter insofar as I just fell over Haagerup 2 (also called H6) in arxiv1102.2631v2 which I forgot - so we're down to rank 6 anyway.

Comment: You cite [Quantum subgroups of the Haagerup fusion categories](http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.2631) by Grossman-Snyder, p15.